# Eclipse - Extend default visual editor with custom widgets

Tags: eclipse, dojo

I'm using Eclipse as default IDE. In Eclipse there is a visual editor available to insert `HTML` tags in your `*.html` files. I'm using a lot of `DOJO` in my current project and want to add these widgets to the `palette` view. I assumed that there would be an option to add custom widgets/tags easily(palette's contextmenu or something), but this is not (yet) implemented. Does somebody knows if there is an option to add custom widgets in Eclipse?

I've already Googled a lot and didn't found where I am looking for.

ps. I don't want to use other editors(Maqetta, WDT-plugin, ...).

Comment: Good question, I am looking for the same thing.